# How to apply __str__ method to subclass of abstract superclass class

Tags: python, django, string, django-models

I have 3 models, one of which is an Abstract superclass and two of which are subclasses if that superclass.

I am trying to implement a simple **str**  method on the model, but no matter the implementation it throws me this error:

```
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

Here are my models:

```
class DemandBase(models.Model):
    demand          = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    building        = models.ForeignKey(Building, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class DemandHeat(DemandBase):

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)


class DemandCool(DemandBase):

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

Ok so I tried casting it as in the example above, but I tried also the following without success:

```
return "This is an example {}".format(self.demand)
```

and this

```
return f"This is an example {self.demand}"
```

and this:

```
return "this is a string"
```

All these alternatives work on normal models, but here it doesn't, so I assume it has to do with the inheritance or the abstraction of the class.....

Any help or hints are very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I also get this error when I try to create a new BuildingGroup in the admin. It also has a ForeignKey to buildings as m2m relation. The model looks like this:

```
class BuildingGroup(models.Model):
    description           = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    project               = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    buildings             = models.ManyToManyField(Building, default=None, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
```

Comment: None of those would give that error. There is something else wrong. Are you sure the indentation is correct? Do you have another `__str__` model defined on the base class?

Comment: This has nothing to do with abstract models. In fact Django is not aware of the `__str__` function itself.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. @Daniel Well, indentation should be fine I guess and I do not have another string method for the base class. Also because I wouldn't want to return anything for the base class since it is abstract. Or am I wrong and should I implement one?

Comment: or maybe because I don't have any field declared? But I assumed inheritance would take care of that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not reproduce your bug.
Migrations ran just fine as shown bellow:

```
  example/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model DemandCool
    - Create model DemandHeat
```

I'm using Django==2.2.3

Wrote same model, excluding ForeignKey (should make no difference at all)

**example/models.py**

```
  1 from django.db import models                                                                                       
  2                                                                                       
  3                                                                                                                    
  4 class DemandBase(models.Model):                                                                                    
  5     demand = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)                                                              
  6                                                                                                                    
  7     class Meta:                                                                                                    
  8     ┆   abstract = True                                                                                            
  9                                                                                                                    
 10                                                                                                                    
 11 class DemandHeat(DemandBase):                                                                                      
 12                                                                                                                    
 13     def __str__(self):                                                                                             
 14     ┆   return str(self.id)                                                                                        
 15                                                                                                                    
 16                                                                                                                    
 17 class DemandCool(DemandBase):                                                                                      
 18                                                                                                                    
 19     def __str__(self):                                                                                             
 20     ┆   return str(self.id)                                                                                        
 21
```

**python manage.py shell**

```
Python 3.6.8 (default, Jan 14 2019, 11:02:34) 
[GCC 8.0.1 20180414 (experimental) [trunk revision 259383]] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from example.models import DemandHeat
>>> instance = DemandHeat(demand=0.7)
>>> instance.save()
>>> instance.__str__()
'1'
>>> print(instance)
1
```

Comment: thank you for your effort my friend. While debugging today I realised that I also get the same error when I want to create a new building group. (a model I excluded from the question, since I thought it is irrelevant). I edited my question accordingly....

Comment: Could you show the context where you are calling the method?

Comment: I could finally solve the problem, yet I still don't know exactly what was going wrong. First, I deleted my models. Then, since I am using docker I removed all my containers and images and built everything new. Then I wrote the models again, which solved it. Must have been sth with the db.Apologies if that question was maybe off topic then, but I honestly believed it was a problem with abstract classes. Thank you again João for the help. Knowing that you couldn't reproduce the error led me into the right direction.